# issue while adding recipie

Tags: magento2, extensions, acl

I have created a user . I give a user role and give resources to add recipies . it is working for admin user . but it is not working for non admins . screenshots will help you understand my question. 
[image]

and for non admin users .
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Mageside. All rights reserved.
 * See MS-LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::content">
                    <resource id="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage" title="Mageside Recipes Manage"/>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Mageside_Recipe::config_mageside_recipe" title="Mageside Recipes Config" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**menu.xml is**

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Mageside. All rights reserved.
 * See MS-LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
-->
    <menu>
        <add id="Mageside_Recipe::recipe"
             title="Recipes"
             translate="title"
             module="Mageside_Recipe"
             sortOrder="50"
             parent="Magento_Backend::content"
             dependsOnModule="Mageside_Recipe"
             resource="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage"/>
        <add id="Mageside_Recipe::recipe_menu"
             title="Manage Recipes"
             translate="title"
             module="Mageside_Recipe"
             sortOrder="55"
             resource="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage"
             parent="Mageside_Recipe::recipe"
             action="recipe/recipe/manage"/>
        <add id="Mageside_Recipe::recipe_menu_filter"
             title="Recipe Filters"
             translate="title"
             module="Mageside_Recipe"
             sortOrder="60"
             resource="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage"
             parent="Mageside_Recipe::recipe"
             action="recipe/recipe/filter"/>
        <add id="Mageside_Recipe::recipe_menu_reviews"
             title="Recipe Reviews"
             translate="title"
             module="Mageside_Recipe"
             sortOrder="70"
             resource="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage"
             parent="Mageside_Recipe::recipe"
             action="recipe/reviews/manage"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: share your acl.xml

Comment: share you menu.xml too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two thing you have to check..

your controller have

```
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage';
```

and your `Vendor/modulename/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` have same resource id too

```
resource="Mageside_Recipe::mageside_recipe_manage"
```

Comment: yes they are same .